# Grails one to many relationship view

Tags: grails, grails-orm, one-to-many

I have two grails domain classes

```
 Class MultipleChoiceQuestion {
    String question
    static constraints = {
        ...
    }
    static hasMany = [options:MultipleChoiceOption]
   }
```

and

```
class MultipleChoiceOption{
    String answerOption
    boolean correctOption
    MultipleChoiceQuestion question
    static constraints = {
        ...
    }
}
```

I want my users to be able to create a question then add atleast 3 options without navigating/clicking on different screens.

My first question is must I generate view and start editing code?

And if the answer to question above is yes then my second question is, what's the best way to save a question along with multiple options in one form submit?
The generated code will have something like following for each option.

```
<g:textField name="answerOption" value="${answerOptionInstance?.answerOption}"/>
<g:checkBox name="correctOption" value="${answerOptionInstance?.correctOption}"/>
```

how can I have multiple such elements in one page?
Please see the wireframe to get an idea of what I want to achieve, my apologies  for poorly created wire frame.
Click on the link for opening the image in your browser
http://cynosuredev.com/wf.png
[image: Wireframe]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maybe this site will help you
http://omarello.com/2010/08/grails-one-to-many-dynamic-forms/

Comment: this seems like what I need from the screenshots but the example code does not seem to be working on my environment, and I am not able to understand how is it creating multiple instances of one domain class from one GSP

Comment: Error 2012-01-08 03:00:41,733 ["http-bio-8080"-exec-5] ERROR hibernate.AssertionFailure  - an assertion failure occured (this may indicate a bug in Hibernate, but is more likely due to unsafe use of the session)
Message: null id in blog.omarello.Phone entry (don't flush the Session after an exception occurs)
   Line | Method
->>  43 | doCall  in blog.omarello.ContactController$_closure4$$ENLMAh4X
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   886 | runTask in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
|   908 | run . . in     ''

Comment: ok I found it, I change in the template gsp (_phone/_phones) the name of the input need to match with the property name.
It was define 'phoneList' instead of 'phones'; the many relation is done upon the name.
http://pastebin.com/uqbLBZZd

Comment: It might be too much to ask for but can you please tell me how will it work with a checkbox? I have the following code      
          
<g:textField controller="multipleChoiceOption" name="options[${i}].answerOption" action="show" id="${o?.id}" value="${o?.encodeAsHTML()}"/>
        <g:checkBox name="options[${i}].correctOption" value="${o?.correctOption}"/><br/>

This works when inserting or updating values to true. But when I uncheck a checkbox there is no change reflected !Some of the code is submitted here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8787110/grails-empy-entry-into-the-database

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use Grails scaffolding if you don't want to. Since this is a pretty specialized form, you should construct the HTML yourself. I've created a test project at [github](https://github.com/leadVisionary/Grails-Survey-Module) that shows a good design for this problem. Check it out.