# How to save multiple object from one view using Grails

Tags: grails, grails-orm, one-to-many

This question is in follow up to this post [Grails one to many relationship view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8758232/grails-one-to-many-relationship-view)

The example suggested there is not working and throwing following exception at run time

```
null id in blog.omarello.Phone entry (don't flush the Session after an exception occurs). Stacktrace follows:
Message: null id in blog.omarello.Phone entry (don't flush the Session after an exception occurs)
   Line | Method
->>  43 | doCall  in blog.omarello.ContactController$_closure4$$ENLORkU6
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   886 | runTask in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
|   908 | run . . in     ''
^   662 | run     in java.lang.Thread
```

I think rather then making the example work can any one help me understand how can I create a GSP which can let me save multiple instances of same domain class. For example, a GSP which can let me insert multiple Book instances at once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the Contact class in the phone example as follows and it should work fine.

```
package blog.omarello

import org.apache.commons.collections.list.LazyList;
import org.apache.commons.collections.FactoryUtils;

class Contact {

    static constraints = {
        firstName(blank:false)
        lastName(blank:false)
    }

    String firstName
    String lastName
    String nickName


 List phones = LazyList.decorate(new ArrayList(),
                                  FactoryUtils.instantiateFactory(Phone.class));


//    List phones = new ArrayList()
    static hasMany = [ phones:Phone ]

    static mapping = {
        phones cascade:"all-delete-orphan"
    }

//    def getPhonesList() {
//        return LazyList.decorate(
//              phones,
//              FactoryUtils.instantiateFactory(Phone.class))
//    }

    def String toString() {
        return "${lastName}, ${firstName}"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Once again, examine the project I linked on [github](https://github.com/leadVisionary/Grails-Survey-Module). It is a demonstration of some of the one of the better practices for doing this. Particularly, look at the [question/index](https://github.com/leadVisionary/Grails-Survey-Module/blob/master/grails-app/views/question/index.gsp), as this is what the view can look like. The actual saving piece is done in the [QuestionService](https://github.com/leadVisionary/Grails-Survey-Module/blob/master/grails-app/services/com/visionarysoftwaresolutions/QuestionService.groovy), used by the [QuestionController](https://github.com/leadVisionary/Grails-Survey-Module/blob/master/grails-app/controllers/com/visionarysoftwaresolutions/QuestionController.groovy). This project does *exactly* what you're trying to do. Review it.