# Grails empty entry into the database

Tags: grails, grails-orm, gsp

I have been struggling with trying to create/save multiple instances at once in Grails, now I am almost there with the following code but when I hit save an empty row of options is created, can anyone help me with this
please see these two questions to see what I want to achieve

[How to save multiple object from one view using Grails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8776212/how-to-save-multiple-object-from-one-view-using-grails)

[Grails one to many relationship view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8758232/grails-one-to-many-relationship-view)

```
<g:textField name="question" value="${multipleChoiceQuestionInstance?.question}"/><br/>
  <div class="fieldcontain ${hasErrors(bean: multipleChoiceQuestionInstance, field: 'options', 'error')} ">
    <label for="options">
      <g:message code="multipleChoiceQuestion.options.label" default="Options" />

    </label>

    <ul class="one-to-many">
      <g:set var="counter" value="${0}" />
      <g:each  status="i" in="${multipleChoiceQuestionInstance?.options?}" var="o">
        <li>
        <g:textField controller="multipleChoiceOption" name="options[${i}].answerOption" action="show" id="${o.id}" value="${o?.encodeAsHTML()}"/>
        <g:checkBox name="options[${i}].correctOption" value="${o.correctOption}"/><br/>
        </li>
        <g:set var="counter" value="${++counter}" />
      </g:each>
      <li>
      <g:textField name="options[${++counter}].answerOption" value=""/>
      <g:checkBox name="options[${counter}].correctOption" /><br/>
      </li>
      <li class="add">
      <g:link controller="multipleChoiceOption" action="create" params="['multipleChoiceQuestion.id': multipleChoiceQuestionInstance?.id]">${message(code: 'default.add.label', args: [message(code: 'multipleChoiceOption.label', default: 'MultipleChoiceOption')])}</g:link>
      </li>
    </ul>

  </div>
```

If you prefer not to click on the link here are the domain classes

```
Class MultipleChoiceQuestion {
    String question
    static constraints = {
        ...
    }
    static hasMany = [options:MultipleChoiceOption]

class MultipleChoiceOption{
    String answerOption
    boolean correctOption
    MultipleChoiceQuestion question
    static constraints = {
        ...
    }
}

   }
```

I am using automatically generated code by grails for the controller, it is as bellow

```
    def create() {
        [multipleChoiceQuestionInstance: new MultipleChoiceQuestion(params)]
    }

    def save() {
        println params
        def multipleChoiceQuestionInstance = new MultipleChoiceQuestion(params)
        if (!multipleChoiceQuestionInstance.save(flush: true)) {
            render(view: "create", model: [multipleChoiceQuestionInstance: multipleChoiceQuestionInstance])
            return
        }

        flash.message = message(code: 'default.created.message', args: [message(code: 'multipleChoiceQuestion.label', default: 'MultipleChoiceQuestion'), multipleChoiceQuestionInstance.id])
        redirect(action: "show", id: multipleChoiceQuestionInstance.id)
    }

def update() {
        def multipleChoiceQuestionInstance = MultipleChoiceQuestion.get(params.id)
        if (!multipleChoiceQuestionInstance) {
            .... //deleted for real estate
            return
        }

        if (params.version) {
             //version checking stuff
            }
        }

        multipleChoiceQuestionInstance.properties = params

        if (!multipleChoiceQuestionInstance.save(flush: true)) {
            render(view: "edit", model: [multipleChoiceQuestionInstance: multipleChoiceQuestionInstance])
            return
        }

        flash.message = message(code: 'default.updated.message', args: [message(code: 'multipleChoiceQuestion.label', default: 'MultipleChoiceQuestion'), multipleChoiceQuestionInstance.id])
        redirect(action: "show", id: multipleChoiceQuestionInstance.id)
    }
```

Comment: Please post the code where you're saving your entities

Comment: You haven't really told us what your problem is, what behaviour you're seeing at the moment, and what behaviour you would like to see. I don't think too many people are going to read over those two other questions in order to figure out what this wall of GSP code is trying to achieve. Also, you were previously directed towards this project https://github.com/leadVisionary/Grails-Survey-Module which contains a solution for this problem. Was there something about this solution you didn't like?

Comment: @don problem is stated as "when I hit save an empty row of options is created" this means that an empty row without any data is getting created in the database.

Comment: @Grrrrr : Can you post the code that you are using in your controller to persist your entities?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason that you are getting an empty row of options is because you are leaving a textfield with name option[counter] blank. This empty value is passed as a parameter to the controller action and it creates a new row with these blank values.

You should remove any blank options before calling

`multipleChoiceQuestionInstance.properties = params`

You can use something like this :

```
def emptyOptions = params.options.findAll{!it.answerOption}
params.options.removeAll(emptyOptions)
```